# Insert Minus Sign In Each Cell In A Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I really need some help with this one.

I have searched high and low but cannot find a solution.

I have a column '**B**' with around 16,000 rows. Each row contains both text and numbers. (See example)

I need to insert a minus sign in front of each one. How can I do this quickly?

```
**B**
image
00020900(1).JPG
373024H.JPG
And So On
```

I want the end result to look like this `-00020900(1).JPG`

I need a quick formula or Macro to achieve this for each cell in column B.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a separate column, type `="-"&A1` assuming your first cell is `A1` and drag that formula down. Once that is done, copy and paste value on that first column.

Comment: Man you rock! I love StackOverflow!! Thanks! I can select your answer in 15 minutes and upvote when I reach 15 points. Thanks again

Comment: Quick question. Now how do I copy the results without the #REF! showing?

Comment: Do "Paste special" then "Paste values". If you just copy and paste it pastes the formulas and if they go out of range it will show #REF!.

Comment: I got it :) Paste Values